# MAP vs REDUCE which I should choose?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

In this case, I have to format an email list to `JSON`, and both `map` and `reduce` functions do the job, but I get confused, which one should I use, or is there any alternatives?

**Input**

```
const emailList = `
Last name, First name <email@email.com>;
Last name, First name <email@email.com>;
Last name, First name <email@email.com>;
Last name, First name <email@email.com>;
`
```

**Using Map**

```
let formatedList =
  emailList.trim()
  .split(';')
  .map(record => {
    let recordObj = {}
    const [lastname, firstname, email] = record.split(/\,|\</g).map(r => r.trim())

    recordObj['firstname'] = firstname
    recordObj['lastname'] = lastname
    recordObj['email'] = email

    return recordObj
  })
```

**Using Reduce**

```
let formatedList =
  emailList.trim()
  .split(';')
  .reduce((usersObj, record) => {
    let formatedUser = {}
    let [lastname, firstname, email] = record.split(/\,|\</g).map(r => r.trim())

    formatedUser['firstname'] = firstname
    formatedUser['lastname'] = lastname
    formatedUser['email'] = email

    usersObj.push(formatedUser)
    return usersObj;
  }, [])
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "First name",
    "lastname": "Last name",
    "email": "email@email.com>"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "First name",
    "lastname": "Last name",
    "email": "email@email.com>"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: `.map` is the idiomatic one in this case where you have an array and you want to *map* each value of it and produce another array.

Comment: Just one thing `.map(record => { const [lastname, firstname, email] = record.split(/\,|\</g).map(r => r.trim()); return { lastname, firstname, email }; })` *of course adding line breaks*. I find this easier to read than your way of constructing the returned object. And you should get used to actually wrinting the `;` in your code.

Comment: @Thomas absolutely true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1) If you `.map` an array that tells the compiler (and your coworkers) that every element of the array should be transformed into something else, and the results are then collected in a new array.

2) If you `.reduce` an array that tells the compiler (and your coworkers) that all elements of the array get transformed into a new value (yes, that could be an array).

3) You can rewrite every `.map` with `.reduce`, but you can't write `.reduce` with `.map` (at least not in a beautiful way).

Therefore I'd say that `.map` expresses your intent more clearly. Its like preferring "I buy a car" over "I buy a vehicle that is moving and has four wheels and an engine". While both mean the same, the first one is easier to understand.